Chromecast Edge to TV - Sound via external speaker
I have the following situation:
I have a notebook running Windows 11. On this notebook I am doing video conferences via BigBlueButton. I have an external speaker/micro (Anker PowerConf) as sound input and output. Now I use Chromecast in Edge to cast the video conference on my TV (via a Waipu TV-Stick). This means, that the sound is output from the TV speakers while the input is still via the external micro.
I want the sound output to be the external speaker and not the TV speaker. Is this possible and if yes, how can I do this?

So you want to "cast" just the video, and keep the audio going out through the laptop's configured audio device?

@music2myear yes

Under Windows Settings > System > Sound > Volume Mixer, is there an option for both the Waipu and the external speaker next to Output Device?

@squillman no, there is only the internal speaker and the external speaker

Probably you're going to have to take the audio out from the TV to the external speaker.

There are some suggestions on Reddit, but I don't have anything to test using.

@squillman the external speaker is connected to my notebook via USB and does not support bluetooth. The TV is too far away from where I am sitting so that would not work

@music2myear Do you have any links to those suggestions?
